# How to open and edit eclipse(java) project in Atom Text editor

Tags: java, eclipse, editor, atom-editor

I am a front-end developer and I really like working in atom :). Is there a way to set up eclipse project work environment in atom. Eclipse has kind of a weird editor and I have couple of plugins that I use daily in atom. Tried couple things like opening one file in atom but changes I made where not reflected,(only editing in eclipse makes changes)

Would appreciate your help, thanks.

Comment: If you change a file outside of eclipse, you need to hit "refresh" on that file for Eclipse to load the changed file.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Thank for the answer. Is there a live reloading option.